# help in extracting a tag out of a DOM of a web page

Tags: c#

I am creating a C# application in order to get the DOM info of a Web Page.
I cannot extract a TBODY tag using my application.
I am using

- the control WebBrowser shipped by Visual Studio
- a reference to the Com Microsoft.mshtml 7.0.3300.0

If I use the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) ) I can see all information I need.

The  tag has id="tbody_id" and carries a list of  tags full of data
that are showed in attributes innertHTML and innertText.

Using the code below innertHtml and innertText are both null.
What I am doing wrong?
There are other controls that I can use

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument3 domDoc = this.webBrowser.Document.DomDocument as mshtml.IHTMLDocument3;
mshtml.IHTMLElement element = domDoc.getElementById("tbody_id");
String innerHtml = element.innerHTML;
String innerText = element.innerText;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on similar - the only thing you might try is to an implicit cast.

I am doing similar and have no trouble with getElementby

```
  IHTMLDocument3 currDocument3 = (IHTMLDocument3)webBrowser.Document.DomDocument; // Cast browser document
  IHTMLElement element = currDocument3.getElementById("f15188");
```

Hope this helps

Roger

Comment: Hi Roger
I tried this but it doesn't work for me. In my case element variable is not null but the innserText returned by it. After testing different things I found a great control for WebBrowsing free and really good. See the notes I wrote down and follow the links for major and more detailed sample code.
I Thank you very much for your time
AFG

Answer (score 0):

For all interested I finally solved this issue.

I simply switched from the WebBrowser control by Microsoft to [csEXWB](http://groups.google.com/group/csexwb) .

A nice column to see how does it work can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx) where I learnt the code to extract correctly the DOM information.

The control must be registered since ti seems to be a COM component (please read notes on the web site and in the column).

1. Place a cEXWB in your Form like and you will have a web browser control in your app.

   ```
   // your object somewhere
   public csExWB.cEXWB cEXWB1;
   ```
2. Go to the web site  you want

   ```
   cEXWB1.Navigate( "http://stackoverflow.com" )
   ```
3. Once loaded get the DOM and each element you want

   ```
   IHTMLDocument3 domDoc = cEXWB1.WebbrowserObject.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument3;
   IHTMLElement element = domDoc.getElementById("my_id");
   ```